# Using a props Variable in an async Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I am receiving the value of web3 within a vue.js component. I am successfully using this variable earlier in my code in the same component. However, upon trying to use it in an async function, I receive an undefined error on the said variable. Shouldn't I be able to use it as below, or am I missing something? (blockNum is being assigned a value earlier in my code.)

```
 props: ['web3']

 async function getTimestamp () {
     const block = await this.web3.eth.getBlock(blockNum)
     const ts = await this.web3.eth.getBlock(block).timestamp
     return ts
 }
 console.log(getTimestamp())
```

Comment: Use your debugger. I suspect your `this` is being changed due to insufficient binding by the caller of `getTimestamp()`.

Comment: `console.log(getTimestamp())` <-- this does not do what you think it does. All this will do is print `[object Promise]` to the console.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code of your component? Your current snippet doesn't compile.

Comment: `console.log(getTimestamp())` calls `getTimestamp` without a `this` value. It's unclear what you expected it to refer to.

Comment: Add `ts` to data, then instead of `return ts`, do `this.ts = ts`, then plop `this.getTimestamp()` call in the created or mounted hooks, if web3 might not be populated, you should add a `watch:{ web3(v){ if (v) this.getTimestamp() }}` etc, then just access the ts value, you don't need to return things from methods, that's what models are for

Comment: Though, the undefined error is probably triggered from `blockNum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getTimestamp` is an async function, it returns a promise as opposed to the actual value. Therefore, you have to wait for the promise to resolve before console logging it.

```
async function getTimestamp () {
 const block = await this.web3.eth.getBlock(blockNum)
 const ts = await this.web3.eth.getBlock(block).timestamp
 return ts
}

getTimestamp().then(ts => {
    console.log(ts)
}
```